# spring using CGLIB proxy even when class implements interface

Tags: spring, gwt-rpc, spring-aop

I'm trying to use Spring AOP to intercept methods of my GWT-RPC application (using GWT-Server library, so RPC service doesn't extend RemoteServiceServlet). When I deploy my war to tomcat and start the application, CGLIB fails for some reason. But I don't understand why CGLIB is being used for proxying at the first place. Since my RPC class implements the interface, shouldn't it be using JDK dynamic proxies?

Is there anything I need to do to debug this issue? Kindly advise.

Note: FYI, Spring encounters this exception, but I believe that's a different problem, I'm unable to understand why CGLIB proxy is in the picture.

```
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException-->Another unnamed CacheManager already exists 
in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config 
or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same    CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
```

Comment: How does it fail? Can you show the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for the sake of other (rare) folks who might do the same mistake.

The aspect setup for spring AOP wasn't correct and was in fact trying to target almost all the classes in the context, which is why EhCache started causing problems as there were more than one CacheManager instances (because of CGLIB proxies as CacheManager doesn't implement an interface)